# python multithreading issue in cronjob no execute

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, cron, multiprocessing

I have one script.py which calls other multiprocessing scripts as follows my scripts.py:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

scriptspy = [
    '/pyscripts/apoiont01.py',
    '/pyscripts/access.py',
    '/pyscripts/dental.py',
    '/pyscripts/cremers.py',
    '/pyscripts/delcuritib.py',
    '/pyscripts/dtalndes.py',
    '/pyscripts/lobo.py',
    '/pyscripts/ierre.py',
    '/pyscripts/daster.py',
    '/pyscripts/dsul.py',
    '/pyscripts/doema.py',
    '/pyscripts/maz.py',
    '/pyscripts/deura.py',
    '/pyscripts/der.py',
    '/pyscripts/dlo.py',
    '/pyscripts/deoltda.py',
    '/pyscripts/dpeed.py',
    '/pyscripts/derr.py',
    '/pyscripts/dweb.py',
]


def roda_processo(processo):
    os.system('python3.7 {}'.format(processo))


for s in scriptspy:
    roda_processo(s)
```

My crontab -e:

```
* * * * 1,5 /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /pyscripts/scripts.py > /pyscripts/logs/scripts.log
```

Funny thing is, if I run that same manual run command on the terminal: `/ usr / local / bin / python3. 7 /pyscripts/scripts.py > / pyscripts/logs / scripts.log` it runs normally.

Log /var/log/cron.log:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/braganetx/a05c8b7257df79305dd1b79008323011/raw/8aec453a74566e8872608d1705f05004c1e12e5e/log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace this with the version with the full path to the python interpreter, because whatever is run from the `cron` lacks the "usual" environment variables setup, namely, PATH is what you're missing the most:

```
def roda_processo(processo):
    os.system('/usr/local/bin/python3.7 {}'.format(processo))
```

Comment: Okay, I get it.
I'm going to water down the next schedule cycle to see if it's going to run now.

Comment: @JB_ if you find it helpful you may upvote and / or accept the answer =)